# async/await behaviour of mongoose findById

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I have the following code:

```
const checkForRecord = async (id) => {

    let model = mongoose.model('User');

    let query = {}
    query.dummy = false; <== This is field is here to forcely cause an error, as it is not present on my User model.
    let result = await model.findById(id, query);

    console.log('Code reached here !!!');
    console.log(result);
}
```

I´m getting the following error:

```
(node:6680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ...
```

My `console.log`s are not even being called.

Why is that error not being set to result, as my operation is async ?

I´ve tried both:

```
let result = await model.findById(id, query);
```

and

```
let result = await model.findById(id, query).exec();
```

Same behaviour.

Comment: using async/await you should use try/catch for error handling the `await`ed result, see almost every tutorial on async/await for examples .... setting the result to the error would be confusing, no?? how would you know if the result is valid or an error?

Comment: The error seems to indicate whatever your passing to `checkForRecord` as the `id` cannot be cast to an `ObjectId`, can you show us what your `id` is?

Comment: I think the OP is deliberately causing the error - see this - `<== To cause an error, this field is not used`

Comment: `const checkForRecord = async (id) {...` is a syntax error. What does the code actually look like? An arrow function?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My words...

Comment: *"CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ."* Right here is where you cut off the important bit. The value being passed in for `id` is not an valid for an `ObjectId`. We could tell you exactly what was wrong there, but you truncated the error in your question at exactly the point you really needed to show.

Comment: @NeilLunn: I don't think the question is about that error. It's about why they don't see that error in their `result` variable. They're causing the error on purpose.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually near commented on your answer to the effect of "the question actually is about the error". All of the answer is structurally correct of course. However there are also semantic mistakes in the general usage of the database function here that have not been addressed. Hence the comment for the OP to realize what they missed. Clearly they have not "cut and pasted" code, since as you note yourself, there's invalid syntax that would simply not compile. OP Has a history of misunderstanding the functional usage as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn: :-) I guess eventually he/she will come back and we'll find out.

Comment: @NeilLunn, you are corrent. Actually I´m forcing the error and the question is about how the await handle that error. Sorry for misunderstanding - corrected in the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My console.logs are not even being called.

That's correct behavior. It's an `async` function and you're `awaiting` a function returning a promise. That means rejections are modelled as *exceptions*, terminating the `checkForRecord` function.

> Why is that error not being set to `result`, as my operation is async ?

Because it's not a resolution value (which is what `await` gives you), it's a rejection/exception. It may help to look at what the de-sugared vesion of `checkForRecord` looks like, replacing `async` and `await` with their underlying promise operations:

```
// checkForRecord with async/await desugared to their underyling Promise operations
const checkForRecord = (id) => {

    let model = mongoose.model('User');

    let query = {};
    query.dummy = false; // <== To cause an error, this field is not used
    return model.findById(id, query).then(value => {
        let result = value;
        console.log('Code reached here !!!');
        console.log(result);
    });
};
```

As you can see, you don't get to the `console.log`s because they're in a resolution handler; but a rejection doesn't go to a resolution handler, it goes to a rejection handler.

To be clear: I'm not saying you need to change `checkForRecord`. I'm just showing you what the `async`/`await` becomes (in effect) at runtime.

Your `checkForRecord` is fine (other than a missing `=>` and not having the comment on the `query.dummy` line commented). You'd use it like this in an `async` function:

```
try {
    checkForRecord(someId);
} catch (e) {
    // Handle the error here
}
```

...or like this if not in an `async` function:

```
checkForRecord(someId).catch(e => {
    // Handle the error here
});
```

Comment: Humm. Thanks for the explanation.